# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'nseshan.student' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use referential integrity to create a new table that references a primary key in my parent table. However, each time I try to use a foreign key, i get the error

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'nseshan.student' (errno: 150).

Here are my db creation statements:

```
create table department (
  dept_name varchar(15), 
  building varchar(10), 
  budget int, 
  primary key (dept_name)
);    

create table student (
  ID int, 
  name varchar(20), 
  dept_name varchar(15), 
  tot_cred int, 
  primary key (ID), 
  foreign key (dept_name) 
    references department (dept_name) 
    on update cascade 
    on delete cascade
) engine=innodb;
```

Any suggestions? I think I have defined the primary key's correctly in both tables.

Comment: It works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e302 What is your MySQL version? Does it work if you add `ENGINE=InnoDB` to the `department` table? Newer MySQLs default to innodb but older ones defaulted to MyISAM.

Comment: oh i did not know i had to add engine=innodb to every table? I thought it was only to reference the parent table while using foreign keys. Thanks a lot! it works when I added engine=innodb to the parent table department.